# extract each first item from list of tuples in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the column `col` contains an arbitrarily long list of tuples (each tuple is of length 3). Consider the following example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = \
    pd.DataFrame(columns=['date',         'col'],
                  data = [["2009-09-01",  [(201, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(206, 1, 3)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  np.NaN],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6, ), (204, 7, 9)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]]])
```

I want to extract how many times the first number in each tuple occurs in each row. The first number can be only one of the values (`values: list = [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206]`) (e.g. `301` does not occur), and the numbers at position `1` and `2` in the tuple are irrelevant.

I now want to create six new columns, one for each value in `values`, containing the number of occurrences of this number in position 0 of the tuples, e.g. column `201` contains `1` in row 0, since `201` is at position 0 of one tuple in that row.

Expected output is this:

```
#          date                                        col   a  b  c  d  e  f
# 0  2009-09-01    [(205, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]   1  0  0  0  0  2
# 1  2009-09-01                              [(206, 1, 3)]   0  0  0  0  0  1
# 2  2009-09-01                                        NaN   0  0  0  0  0  0
# 3  2009-09-01  [(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]   2  1  0  0  0  0
# 4  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6, ), (204, 7, 9)]   0  1  1  1  0  0
# 5  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]   0  3  0  0  0  0
```

I am thinking of something like this:

```
for v in values():
    df[str(v)] = # number of occurrences of k at position 0 in col
```

I have experimented with different combinations of `apply(lambda x: ...)` and `str.get` without success; can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You should iterate through the rows instead. For each row evaluate the string containing the list ("ast.literal_eval"). Then iterate through the list and for each number at index 0 of tuple increment the value in the appropriate row and column. There may be slightly faster approaches but this is a very simple one.

Comment: do you have a specific idea? (However, my dataframe has ca. 200 mio rows, so I think that a vectorized approach might be preferable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Series.apply` to apply the logic row-wise to every element of 'col' column, and create the extra columns. Finally, use `DataFrame.join` to add those extra columns to the original DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

df = \
    pd.DataFrame(columns=['date',         'col'],
                  data = [["2009-09-01",  [(201, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(206, 1, 3)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  np.NaN],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6, ), (204, 7, 9)]],
                          ["2009-09-01",  [(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]]])

# create a set instead of a list for O(1) membership test
values = {201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206}
# to rename columns as in the example
column_mapper = dict(zip(sorted(values), "abcdef"))

def count_values(lst):
    # initialize the counts to zero for every element of values
    counts = Counter({n: 0 for n in values})  
    if lst is np.nan:
        return pd.Series(counts)  # if it's Nan return zero counts
    # update the counts based on first element of each tuple 
    counts.update(x for x, *_ in lst if x in values)
    return pd.Series(counts)


df = (
    df.join(df['col'].apply(count_values))
      .rename(columns=column_mapper)  # optional columns renaming
)
```

**Output**

```
>>> df

         date                                        col  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  2009-09-01    [(201, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]  1  0  0  0  0  2
1  2009-09-01                              [(206, 1, 3)]  0  0  0  0  0  1
2  2009-09-01                                        NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  2009-09-01  [(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]  2  1  0  0  0  0
4  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6, ), (204, 7, 9)]  0  1  1  1  0  0
5  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]  0  3  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks! The real data already contains the datatype list in the respective column. However, if I remove the line `lst = ast.litera_eval(lst_str)` (and rename `lst_str` to `lst`), I receive a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Is there a better way than df['col'].astype('string').apply(count_values)`?

Comment: @Ivo then why did you create an example with the string lists instead of lists? Please edit your post with the correct datatype of 'col' to avoid confusion for someone who reads this post in the future. I will edit by answer accordingly, assuming that the elements of 'col' are lists from the beginning.

Comment: @Ivo I see that you've already edited, thanks! Consider accepting the answer if it works as intended. If it doesn't work I can help you understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over all rows you could use `apply`, which should be significantly faster:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date',         'col'],
                  data = [["2009-09-01",  "[(201, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]"],
                          ["2009-09-01",  "[(206, 1, 3)]"],
                          ["2009-09-01",  np.NaN],
                          ["2009-09-01",  "[(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]"],
                          ["2009-09-01",  "[(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6, ), (204, 7, 9)]"],
                          ["2009-09-01",  "[(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6, ), (202, 7, 9)]"]])

values = [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206]
# converting strings to lists
df["col"] = df["col"].apply(lambda x: x if type(x)!= str else ast.literal_eval(x))

def get_index_from_list_of_tuples(l: list, v: int):
    try:
        return list(map(lambda t: t[0], l)).index(v) + 1
    except:
        return 0

for v in values:
    df[v] = df["col"].apply(lambda x: get_index_from_list_of_tuples(x, v))
```

Output:

```
         date                                      col  201  202  203  204  205  206
0  2009-09-01  [(201, 0, 2), (206, 4, 6), (206, 6, 8)]    1    0    0    0    0    2
1  2009-09-01                            [(206, 1, 3)]    0    0    0    0    0    1
2  2009-09-01                                      NaN    0    0    0    0    0    0
3  2009-09-01  [(201, 0, 2), (201, 4, 6), (202, 7, 9)]    1    3    0    0    0    0
4  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (203, 4, 6), (204, 7, 9)]    0    1    2    3    0    0
5  2009-09-01  [(202, 0, 2), (202, 4, 6), (202, 7, 9)]    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Note: you can move `literal_eval` inside the function for more efficiency. It's not clear why you'd keep your lists as strings though.